# MySQLi вопрос по подготовленным выражениям

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть страница с формой поиска, текст которого передается через форму.

Получаю:

```
$where = "";
if(isset($_GET['search']))
    $where = "WHERE `action` LIKE '%" . $_GET['search'] . "%'";
```

Далее подключаюсь к БД и:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `logs` ? ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ?, 50')) 
{
      $result->bind_param("sd", $where, $limit);

      $limit = ($page - 1) * 50;

      $result->execute();

      $result = $result->get_result();
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      { 
          printf("<tr><td class='tg-3we0'>%s</td>", $row['date']);
          printf("<td class='tg-3we0'><font color='%s'>%s</font></td>", GetColor($row['class']), $row['action']);
      }
      $result->close(); 
}
```

И ничего. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: нельзя биндить ключевые фразы а-ля `WHERE`, `FROM` и прочее......только поля таблицы ........например `$where = "WHERE action LIKE '%?%'";`......`SELECT * FROM logs '.$where.' ORDER BY`....`$result->bind_param('s',$_GET['search']);` ..........а биндить целое выражение невозможно

Comment: И то с `LIKE`  вот так должно быть `WHERE action LIKE ?` ......`$result->bind_param('s','%'.$_GET['search'].'%');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Биндинг - не самоцель. Это только средство. А цель - чтобы запрос, отправляемый в базу данных, **всегда был прописан программистом весь целиком в коде скрипта**. Для этого и служит биндинг, подставляя на место переменных знаки вопроса.

Поэтому для решения конкретно этой проблемы мы комбинируем биндинг с прописанными в скрипте элементами запроса.

```
$where = '';
if(isset($_GET['search']))
    $where = "WHERE `action` LIKE ?"; 
    $serach = "%" . $_GET['search'] . "%";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `logs` $where ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT ?, 50";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
if ($where)
{
    $result->bind_param("si", $where, $limit);
} else {
    $result->bind_param("i", $limit);
}
$limit = ($page - 1) * 50;
$stmt->execute();
$result = $result->get_result();
```

Плюс ко всему, этот вопрос наглядно демонстрирует, почему надо использовать враппер, а не шарашить на голом mysqli. К примеру, с помощью PDO код получится в два раза короче

```
$params['limit'] = ($page - 1) * 50;
$where = '';
if(isset($_GET['search']))
    $where = "WHERE `action` LIKE :search"; 
    $params['search'] = "%" . $_GET['search'] . "%";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `logs` $where ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT :limit, 50";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Но главное что в обоих случаях запрос на 100% жестко прописан в коде скрипта - то есть, инъекцию попросту некуда впихнуть - все данные в БД предаются отдельно от запроса*.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо.